# How to use nunique value counts of a single column after groupby to apply some condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to save the ids into a list which have nunique() value counts greater than some threshold.

`temp=df.groupby('id')['random_column'].nunique().sort_values(ascending=False)`

The above command gives all ids with their unique count values but the *count_values* do not have any column_name due to which when I try to put some condition for eg. `temp[temp.random_column>1]`,

I get

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'random_column'`.

But, when I add another column in the entire command, I don't get above error:
`temp=df.groupby('id')['random_column', 'one_more_column'].nunique()`

`temp[temp.random_column>1]` works fine.

Why can't I use a single column to do the same?

Comment: You need to use the resulting boolean vector to perform the subsetting. Probably something like `temp.id[temp['count'] > 1]`. where 'count' may be 'random_column'.

Comment: @Imo Thank you for your suggestion. I was making a mistake of not resetting the index.